# Cross Compiling Boost for use on the Gumstix Overo with GumROS

Tags: boost, cross-compiling, bjam

I'm trying to cross-compile boost for use with the ROS framework on a Gumstix Overo. I've been following the posted instructions here (modifying the script when need be), however I've come across an issue where bjam will not compile boost properly.

I call bjam as follows:

```
# boost
if [ ! -f /opt/gumros/lib/libboost_date_time-gcc41-mt-1_38.so ] ; then
  if [ ! -f boost_1_38_0.tar.gz ] ; then
    wget --tries=10 http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/boost/boost_1_38_0.tar.gz

  fi
#  tar xzf boost_1_38_0.tar.gz
  cd boost_1_38_0
  GPP_PATH=${OVEROTOP}/tmp/cross/armv7a/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/g++
  GPP_VER=`${GPP_PATH} -v 2>&1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}'`
  echo "using gcc : ${GPP_VER} : ${GPP_PATH}  ; " > tools/build/v2/user-config.jam
  sudo apt-get install bjam
  set +o errexit
  sudo bjam --toolset=gcc-${GPP_VER} --prefix=/opt/gumros --with-date_time install                  
  set -o errexit
  cd ..
else
  echo "boost appears to be already installed; skipping."
fi
if [ ! -f /opt/gumros/lib/libboost_date_time-gcc41-mt-1_38.so ] ; then
  echo "Failed to compile libboost_date_time";
  exit;
fi
```

I've checked the user-config to make sure everything was kosher as well as making sure the GPP_PATH is correct. However, when I run the script I come across compilation errors such as:

> Reading package lists... Done Building
>   dependency tree        Reading state
>   information... Done bjam is already
>   the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0
>   newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not
>   upgraded. ...patience... ...found
>   14370 targets... ...updating 14
>   targets... gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.3.3/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o
>   g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus':
>   execvp: No such file or directory
>
> ```
> "/home/andrew/overo-oe/tmp/cross/armv7a/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/g++"
> ```
>
> -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.3.3/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o"
>   "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp"
>
> ...failed gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.3.3/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o...
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.3.3/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o
>   g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus':
>   execvp: No such file or directory
>
> ```
> "/home/andrew/overo-oe/tmp/cross/armv7a/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/g++"
> ```
>
> -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.3.3/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o"
>   "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_weekday.cpp"
>
> ...failed gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.3.3/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o...
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.3.3/release/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o
>   g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus':
>   execvp: No such file or directory

Etc...

For reference, I'm using this tutorial to help me out. http://www.ros.org/wiki/gumros

Comment: @amelim: line 2 >here<, where?

Answer (score 1):

Does running

```
"/home/andrew/overo-oe/tmp/cross/armv7a/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/g++"
-ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.3.3/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o"
"libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_weekday.cpp"
```

by hand give the same error? If so, it seems like your compiler might be incorrectly installed.